# Where can I find names of regions in cartographic report in IBM Cognos Analytics?

Tags: cognos

I have a map report in Cognos Analytics. It pulls up the names of the regions from the database. However, not all region names correlate with those stored in the Cognos database. For example, he does not see the region "Moscow" anywhere.

I tried to correct the names of values ​​at the report level, for example, if the database says "Moscow - a city of federal significance", through CASE I prescribe "Moscow" or "Moscow - the capital of Russia" and other variations of the name of the region. However, Cognos does not recognize it.

Tell me, please, where can I found the names of the regions in Cognos?

Comment: We'll need more information about what you have tried.  For example, Cognos doesn't contain any data.  So where do those values come from?

Comment: @dougp, as a source of data I use two tabels from database: lookup table and fact table. First table joins with fact table so I can analyze data from fact by regions. Lookup table contains attribute with regions. These tables connects to the report. Cognos automatically recognizes the name of the region and placed it on the map report so I can see indicators by regions. But some regions Cognos doesn't recognize, as I undestand, because of there is no regions with such name in Cognos. So I need to find the list of 'true' names, which Cognos can recognize and change these names in database.

Comment: "Placed it on the map report"  Do you mean you are adding data items to a map visualization?  Which one?  How did you configure it?

Comment: @dougp, I configure it via Cognos Framework Manager. I created a new project where I added all tables and joins between them. Then I created a package and publish it on server. After that I made a visualization in Cognos Analytics, where I put my attribute 'Regions' in pull 'Regions' in Cognos. And in pull 'Color' I put my indicator, which I analyze. After that some of the regions painted over correctly according to indicator meaining but some of them Cognos didn't recognize and they didn't stained.

Comment: "I made a visualization"  So this is a custom viz?

Comment: @dougp No, it is build-in visualiztion of Cognos Analytics. I just made a report, then chose visualiztion->Map.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have set the map visualization to use Regions or Point.  You'll need to ensure that whatever data item is in the Locations box contains values that MapBox recognizes as regions (country, state, county) or points (city).  Spelling of these locations probably depends on the locale you're using to access MapBox.

Alternatively, IBM provides documentation describing how to create your own MapBox content:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=maps-setting-up-mapbox-work-cognos-analytics

And don't forget to review the [Cognos Analytics 11.0.5 Mapping and Visualization FAQ](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/businessanalytics/blogs/kevin-mcfaul/2016/12/05/cognos-analytics-1105-mapping-and-visualization-faq) for more information.